# PHP use class function on sub-functions

Tags: php

i have test class with one function , after including that i can use this class function with included pages but i cant use this function on included page's functions, for example:

**testClass.php**:

```
class test
{
    public function alert_test( $message )
     {
       return $message;
     }
}
```

including class:
in this using class i dont have problem

**text.php**:

```
<?php
include 'testClass.php';
$t= new test;
echo alert_test('HELLO WORLD');
?>
```

but i cant use alert_test function with this method:

```
<?php
include 'testClass.php';
$t= new test;
function test1 ( $message )
{
       echo alert_test('HELLO WORLD');
/*
       OR

       echo $t->alert_test('HELLO WORLD');
*/
 }
 ?>
```

i want to use test class in sub-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the instance (`$t`) to your function, i.e:

```
<?php

class test
{
    public function alert_test( $message )
     {
       return $message;
     }
}

$t = new test;

function test1 ( $message, $t )
{
    echo $t->alert_test('HELLO WORLD');
}
```

As an alternative (better IMHO) you could declare your function as `static`, so that you don't even need to instantiate the `test` class, i.e:

```
class Message {
  static function alert($message) {
    echo $message;
  }
}

function test_alert($msg) {
  Message::alert($msg);
}

test_alert('hello world');
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont like use alert_test function in class file

Answer (score 1):

What about `echo $t->alert_test('HELLO WORLD');`? You have to 'tell' PHP where he has to find that function, in this case in $t which is an instance of the test class.

```
<?php
include 'testClass.php';
function test1 ( $message )
{
   $t = new test;
   echo $t->alert_test('HELLO WORLD');
}
?>
```

Comment: `Call to a member function alert_test() on a non-object in ...`

Answer (score 0):

You should "have problem" even in your first example, because `alert_test()` is an instance function of your `test` class.

You have to invoke instance methods as:

```
$instance -> method( $params );
```

So:

```
$t -> alert_test();
```

But local functions [as your `test1`] should not rely on global objects: pass them as a function argument, if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures:

```
$t = new test;
function test1($message) use ($t) {
    $t->test_alert($message);
}
```